# Provide access to multiple azure storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I need to provide read and list access to all the resource types in 75 different storage accounts and sadly I can not create an IAM user for that.

I could create SAS, however, that would require me to create 75 different SAS for each storage account.

I have tried to come up with some sort of a for loop that would do this for me, however, it seems like I'd still need to do lots of manual work in order for this to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

resourceType="sco"
permissions="rl"
expiry=$(date -u -d "next month" +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ)
storageAccounts=$(az storage account list --query "[].name" --output tsv)

for account in $storageAccounts; do
    sas=$(az storage account generate-sas \
        --account-name $account \
        --resource-types $resourceType \
        --services bfqt \
        --permissions $permissions \
        --expiry $expiry \
        --output tsv)
    echo "SAS token for $account:"
    echo "https://$account.blob.core.windows.net/?$sas"
done
```

I was wondering is there any other smart way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do the same way as you do and by using below process and I guess this is the only way to do it and I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest) and [Microsoft-Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-cli):

Firstly got all the storage accounts using below command:

```
rgp="resource grp name"

stAcc=$(az storage account list \
    --resource-group $rgp \
    --query '[].name' \
    --output tsv)

echo "Storage accounts in $rgp:"
echo "$stAcc"
```

[image]

Then created sas token for the above storage accounts using below command:

```
for s in $stAcc; do
 sasTkn=$(az storage account generate-sas \
        --account-name $s \
        --expiry $(date -d "1 day" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ') \
        --permissions rwdlac \
        --resource-types sco \
        --services b \
        --https-only \
        --output tsv) 
        
    echo "SAS token for $s: $sasTkn"
done
```

Output:

[image]

This is the way because you firstly need names of storage accounts then only you can generate SAS token.